# Javascript - Pass function argument into variable name

Tags: javascript, variables, arguments

I am trying to pass a function argument into a variable (if this is possible) to reduce code repetitiveness and nested if statements/ switch statements.  Through research, I discovered the getElementById reference would need to be place in quotes to show up as an id.  The main question is, can I pass the argument into a variable name?

```
<body>
<div class="contain">
    <h3 id="red">0</h3>
        <h3 id="green">0</h3>
        <h3 id="blue">0</h3>
    <button onClick="player_one.addResource(4,green)">Add Green</button>
        <button onClick="player_one.addResource(3,red)">Add Red</button>
        <button onClick="player_one.addResource(7,blue)">Add Blue</button>
</div>

<script>
    var redResource = 0;
    var greenResource = 0;
    var blueResource = 0;

    var player_one = {
    addResource: function(num,color){
        (color)Resource += num
        document.getElementById(color).innerHTML =((color)Resource);
    }

    }

 </script>
 </body>
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
 //with a different approach, I still have an issue
  var player_one = {
addResource: function(num,color){
        player_one.color += num
        document.getElementById(color).innerHTML =    (player_one.color);
    },

  red: 0,
  green: 0,
  blue: 0


  }
```

Comment: your "different approach" will not work better. see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is bad coding, but here is your answser:

```js
var
  redResource = 0,
  greenResource = 0,
  blueResource = 0
;

var player_one = {
  addResource: function(num,color){
    window[color+'Resource'] += num;
    document.getElementById(color).innerHTML = window[color+'Resource'];
  }
}
```

```css
#red { color:red }
#green { color:green }
#blue { color:blue }
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <h3 id="red">0</h3>
  <h3 id="green">0</h3>
  <h3 id="blue">0</h3>
  <button onClick="player_one.addResource(4,'green')">Add Green</button>
  <button onClick="player_one.addResource(3,'red')">Add Red</button>
  <button onClick="player_one.addResource(7,'blue')">Add Blue</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfect as well.   I actually came across the window[] approach at some point in my research, but could not get it to work.   Can you explain why this would be considered bad coding?  And the window[] approach is new to me.  Is there a reference that teaches this?

Comment: I changed to this answer, as it is the correct answer for the way the question was posed.  Even though the creating object approach was a better solution to my overall goal.   Is using the window[ ] approach the only way to insert the argument into the variable name?

Comment: while JS is object, but in your case, you should choose to create your own object as : `var Ressource = { red:0, green:0, blue:0 };` and use it like :  `Ressource[color] += num;`

Comment: [everything in JS is object].
using window[ variable name ] is not a good idea. there is many property and methods on this top object, like   window.length or window.name... (window['length'], window['name'], ...). and maybe tomorow there where window['blue'], window['red'] in the global window scope and your code will not longuer working

Answer (score 3):

instead of variables, you can use an Object :

```
var resources = {
  red: 0,
  green: 0,
  blue: 0
};

var player_one = {
  addResource: function(num, color) {
    resources[color] += num;
    document.getElementById(color).innerHTML = resources[color];
  }
};
```

Comment: This one did not trigger the id correctly. However, when I tried with an id already selected, the result of the innerHTML came back as NaN.

Answer (score 0):

it will be better to use object for it instead of doing some trickery

```js
var player_one = {
addResource: function(num,color){

        player_one[color] += num
        document.getElementById(color).innerHTML =    (player_one[color]);
    },

  red: 0,
  green: 0,
  blue: 0


  }

// console.log(document.getElementById('green'))
```

```html
<div class="contain">
    <h3 id="red">0</h3>
        <h3 id="green">0</h3>
        <h3 id="blue">0</h3>
    <button onClick="player_one.addResource(4,'green')">Add Green</button>
        <button onClick="player_one.addResource(3,'red')">Add Red</button>
        <button onClick="player_one.addResource(7,'blue')">Add Blue</button>
</div>
```

what you were missing was calling the function with string arguments .. as in `func(3, 'red')` and not `func(3, red)`

and in javascript `player_one[color]` and not `player_one.color`

Comment: `(color)Resource` you missed one

Comment: This one did not trigger the id correctly.  However, when I tried with an id already selected,  the result of the innerHTML came back as NaN.

Comment: This worked perfect!    I tried it on my own page, but it still wasn't working. But I figured out I was using double quotes within the double quotes of the button. Changed to single quotes around the color, it worked.   Thank you!

Comment: sure, i am glad :)